# How to execute a slot or a function with two signals in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a QT project. I was wondering if is possible to create a `connection` using two signals to execute a method.

I have three classes: A, B and C. Class A emit a signal when a button is pressed (connected in Class C), also in Class C a `QProcess` is created (from an instance of class B).

In class C I have a `connect` to get the output of the `QProcess`. Also, I have another `connect` to execute a method when a button is pressed (signal emitted in Class A).

So, I need to modify the current behavior, the `doSomething()` method should be executed when the QProcess output is ready, similar to an `if` statement:

```
if(signalA && signal B){
  do something...
}
```

This is the current code:

```
//This signal will get the output of a Qprocess
connect(objectC,&QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [=] (){
    QString out = objectB->readAllStandardOutput();
    qDebug() << out;
});

//When a button in Class A is pressed doSomething() is executed
//but now I must wait until the above signal generates an output.
connect(objectA, ClassA::buttonPressed, [=] (){
    doSomething();
});

objectC -> run(args); // This line execute an external process
```

any Ideas on how to achieve this?

I found on `stackoverflow` that in QT we can have two signals in a single `connect`, like this:

```
connect(this,SIGNAL(someSignal()),this,SIGNAL(anotherSignal()));
```

but I don't know how to adapt this to my problem.

The flow of my QT application is the following:

- A `QProcess` is created to launch an external .exe file
- The `QProcess` return a `QString`
- At any moment the user can press a button that will execute a specific method (`doSomething()`) but needs the output of the `QProcess`.
- The big issue is that sometimes the user press the button before the QProcess ends, so I cannot execute the `doSomething()` correctly.
- The desired behavior is: if the user press the button to execute `doSomething()`, first I must wait until the output of the QProcess is ready. So if I press the button and if the `QProcess` takes e.g 10s to finish, the `doSomething()` should be executed after this 10s.

Comment: That last example you cite is not connecting two signals to a single slot. It is using the second signal (`anotherSignal`) AS a slot. Effectively, this means emitting the first signal will also trigger the second signal. That's not what you seem to be trying to do.

Comment: There's something strange about this design. From your description I've got an impression that those two signals are independent and you cannot make assumption which of them might be fired first. Yet the natural course of the events seems to be the following: the user presses the button which triggers a slot running a `QProcess`, which later sends a signal that the process has finished and the output is ready which triggers the `doSomething` slot. Isn't it what you want? Please describe in more details what are the signals and also their sequence if I'm wrong.

Comment: You desired behavior is not well-defined. You should first know what should be the order of signals, min/max time between two signals, and the situation you reset the current state of possible flags.

Comment: @absolute.madness, exactly, both signals are independent. In Class C, the QProcess is launched and when it is ready it will return a QString.  But in my project there is a button that will execute the `doSomething` when the press button emit a signal, but now when I press the button I must wait for the output before execute the `doSomething`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the state of both events and check them both whenever one of them changes.

```
// These should probably be defined in the header of your class.
bool processFinished = false;
bool buttonClicked = false;

void checkState() {
    if (buttonClicked && processFinished) {
        doSomething();
    }
}

connect(objectC,&QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [=] (){
    ...
    processFinished = true;
    checkState();
});

connect(objectA, ClassA::buttonPressed, [=] (){
    ...
    buttonClicked = true;
    checkState();
});
```

Comment: Hi @JarMan I have a doubt about your suggestion, this will be done only once, right? I mean, if the button is pressed, `checkState` will check if the output is ready, but if it's not ready, the whole process ends, right? So I have to press the button again to check again?
Actually, when the button is pressed, it must wait until the output is ready to execute doSomething. That is, this method must always be executed.

Comment: checkState gets called both when you click the button AND when the output is ready.

Comment: Thanks, I test it and it seems to work, but can you explain me more detailed how it works?, I just want to be 100% sure that the order of the call signals won't  affect the process.

Comment: The order of the signals does not matter. When the output is ready, you set `processFinished` to true and call `checkState()`. That fails because `buttonClicked` has not been set yet. Then later when you press the button, `buttonClicked` is set to true, and `checkState()` is called again. This time it succeeds because both conditions are met. The same thing would happen if the signals occurred in the opposite order.